# Question about finite improper integral and monotonic function

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals

If the improper integral $\int_a^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ is finite, and the function $f(x)$ is a monotonic function, can we get that the function $xf(x)$ is monotonic? I assume there may be some counterexamples, but I just can't find one.

Update: I have found a counterexample. Just take$f(x)=\frac1{n^2},n\leq x<n+1,n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Still, I have another question. Can we prove ${\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}xf(x)lnx}=0$ with the condition that $\int_a^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ is finite and $f(x)$ is monotonic? I'm just unable to find a counterexample.

Comment: First note that if $f$ is monotone and the integral on $[0,\infty]$ is finite then $f$ is monotonically *decreasing*. Second, counter examples to your claim are easy to artificially make; the example $1/x^2$ almost works but isn't integrable around zero, so just fix this. For example, consider $f$ defined by $f(x) = 2-x$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x) = 1/x^2$ for $1 \le x \le \infty$. Then $\int_{[0,\infty]} f(x) = 5/2$ is finite, but $xf(x)$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ and decreasing on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: is the function $f$ defined at $x=0?$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes? $f(0) = 2$ holds trivially as I defined it

Comment: While a  prior comment gives a counterexample, not we would not *expect* your result to hold; we can just take any counterexample without the integrability condition and modify the function to decrease more quickly on some interval $(a, \infty)$ for $a$ large enough to not interfere with $xf(x)$ not being monotone.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$f(x)=e^{-x}$$

$f$ is decreasing at $ [0,+\infty) $ and

$$\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x}dx=1$$

but

$$(xf)'(x)=(1-x)e^{-x}$$

so $x\mapsto xf(x)$ is not monotonic .

Comment: Sry I've edited my question, could you offer me some help again?

Comment: @mmenjorlas_ Your additional condition is also satisfied in the counterexample above.

Comment: emm my question is to prove the limit $xf(x)lnx$ is $0 $or find a counter-example..